# What do the fortune teller words mean?

Tags: meaning

> You're running away from your past and your pain and yet you keep it so close to you.

She says one is running away from your past and your pain, yet she says you are keeping it close to you. How to understand **close** and **away** in same sentence?

Comment: It is called a paradox. It has little to do with English, it is simply that while you _try_ to get away from your pain, you _actually_ still feel it very much. The important word here is **yet**, which signals that the next part of the sentence is going to say something very different from the first part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You're running away from your past and your pain
>   *there has been pain in your past which you are running from to forget*
>
> and yet you keep it so close to you.
>   *as much as you run, you still carry your pain with you. It has possibly become part of your identity*

The fortune teller is saying you must first understand *why* you keep your pain so close to you, otherwise you will not be able to let it go.